# Mongodb insert call not working inside the server

Tags: meteor

I am sure I am making something essentially quite wrong, hope someone can help me here.

I have my mongo model defined in my `/my_project/lib/collections/item.js`

This file has:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const Item = new Mongo.Collection('item', {connection: null});
export default Item;
```

Then, I have my `/my_project/server/server.js` which is:

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
var Item = require('../lib/collections/item.js');

function calculate(params) {

... //removed for brevity

Item.insert({
    key:'key',
    percentage:profit_in_pct,
    createdAt: new Date() // current time
  });

}
```

And the error I am getting is:

> I20170925-12:09:03.457(10)? Exception in callback of async function:
>   TypeError: Item.insert is not a function
>
> I20170925-12:09:03.458(10)?     at Object.calculate
>   (server/server.js:25:8) I20170925-12:09:03.459(10)?     at
>   runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1189:24)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can't you do `import Item from '../lib/collections/item'` which is more inline with the export you are  doing?

Comment: well, that absolutely worked! any idea why? why did import work but require didn't?

Comment: There are several ways of doing modules, and presumably they work a little differently. If you are publishing a package, you have to do several things to support them all (which you clearly weren't)

Comment: That was a vague answer, but I appreciate your support @Mikkel! Take care